# Would getting an MA at a less-than-prestigous school hurt my chances of getting into a prestigious PhD program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters

I'm an economics student who hopes to one day get a PhD. Before doing so, I'd like to get a Master's, both as a way of improving my strength as an applicant and to get a feel for grad school before fully committing myself to the enormous investment that is getting a doctorate. Long story short,for financial reasons I'm thinking about enrolling in the master's program at my local university (UNC Charlotte). It's not a bad school by any means, but it's not exactly Harvard either. Though I'm certain I could get into higher ranked programs, this just makes the most sense for my financial situation. Realistically, would getting a master's at such a school impair my ability to get into a prestigious doctorate program?

Comment: ............No.